# Difference within spells of x and add up by x

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
wpt    ID   Fuel  Dist  Express  
 1     S36   12    1     1         
 2     S36   14    4     1         
 inter S36   15    7     0         
 3     S36   18    10    0         
 inter S36   20    12    1         
 4     S36   23    17    1         
 5     S36   30    20    1         
 6     W09   45    9     0         
 7     W09   48    14    0         
 8     W09   50    15    0
```

The ideal output would be:

```
ID    sum.fuel    sum.dist   Express   
S36     12          11          1         
S36     3           3           0         
W09     5           6           0
```

**NOTE:** The step to get sum.dist under Express 1 for ID "S36" is:

(14-12)+(30-20)=12

to get sum.dist under Express 0 for ID "S36" is:

18-15=3

The same applies for others.

**What's going on** (Frank's guess): We measure fuel consumption and distance at various points along the trip and want to find how much of each we have used during "express" and "local" phases.

**Exactly Frank Guess right**, I want to get efficiency of each type (Express and Local). This's for my project, which I don't know how to deal with. Thanks Frank!

Comment: How did you get those values in `sum.fuel`

Comment: just regular group_by (ID, Express, Local). But this doesn't work, since there are multiple blocks by Express and Local, and they are dummy variable.

Comment: @akrun, see the NOTE part of the post.

Comment: First, subtractions kind of go against the whole "cumulative *sum*" thing. Second, did you lose track of that row with the 23 Fuel in it? Third, these express and local columns should just be a single categorical/factor column.

Comment: @Frank, Thanks I edited the POST. Yes, two level just need one factor. And I don't know how to express the question more specifically..Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Just explain the steps to get your desired values. As Is it's hard to tell how you get 11 as Dist for S36 in  Express mode. Your source and results seems unrelated

Comment: but most importantly, why is cumsum (14-12)+(30-20)?!?!

Comment: @Sotos Arrival minus start for each type if I understand properly. i.e: S36 - Express: line 3 minus line 1 and then line 8 - line 6 (line 7 being a stop inbetween).

Comment: @Sotos,the data is in time series. So I cannot just use the last one substract the first one. I need to do it separately.

Comment: @Sotos, yes, just like that!

Comment: @Tensibai, ah ok. the two columns of Express/Local made it even more confusing.

Comment: @Tensibai, I see, will edit it using just one factor. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @Sotos Indeed, not clear and not intuitive to get :( It's more a diff for each "travel" but it's hard to fidentify travels at all

Comment: @Sotos, I just edited the POST using one factor. It looks more clear now..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I think I get it now, thanks to @Tensibai's explanation:

```
library(data.table)
DF %>% 
  group_by(ID, Express, r = rleid(ID, Express)) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(last(.) - first(.)), Fuel, Dist) %>%
  group_by(ID, Express) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), Fuel, Dist)


     ID Express  Fuel  Dist
  (chr)   (int) (int) (int)
1   S36       1    12    11
2   S36       0     3     3
3   W09       0     5     6
```

*Note*:

> You don't need the second `group_by` statement since the last grouping level (`r`) is "peeled off" by the first `summarise_each`.  – docendo discimus

*How it works*: `rleid` from the data.table package identifies "runs" where a value is constant. If you have data.table installed, you can just do `data.table::rleid` in place of `rleid` and skip loading the package with `library`.

Comment: Appreciate it! Frank

Comment: You don't need the second `group_by` statement since the last grouping level (`r`) is "peeled off" by the first `summarise_each`

Comment: Thanks @docendo . I think I've heard of that behavior before. Personally, I find it unintuitive, though I can see how it might be a nice shortcut.

Answer (score 4):

Yet another alternative with `data.table` without using `lapply` to avoid looping:

Dataset:

```
data <- read.table(text='wpt    ID   Fuel  Dist  Express   Local
 1     S36   12    1     1         0
                   2     S36   14    4     1         0
                   inter S36   15    7     0         1
                   3     S36   18    10    0         1
                   inter S36   20    12    1         0
                   4     S36   23    17    1         0
                   5     S36   30    20    1         0
                   6     W09   45    9     0         1
                   7     W09   48    14    0         1
                   8     W09   50    15    0         1',header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Code:

```
setDT(data) 
# Make a data.table from the dataframe 
# (could be avoided by reading into a datatable directly)

data[,travel:=rleid(ID,Express)] 
# Generate a unique ID per travel
# (same ID, same Express type contiguous)

result <- data[, list(
  V1=max(Fuel)-min(Fuel),
  V2=max(Dist)-min(Dist)
), by=c('ID','Express','travel')][, list(
  sum.fuel = sum(V1),
  sum.dist = sum(V2)
),by = c('ID','Express')]
```

Which gives:

```
    ID Express sum.fuel sum.dist
1: S36       1       12       11
2: S36       0        3        3
3: W09       0        5        6
```

On the Ugly oneliner, here is the same step by step (slower due to copies to show how it works):

```
tmp <- data[, list(
    V1= max(Fuel) - min(Fuel),
    V2= max(Dist) - min(Dist)
), by=c('ID','Express','travel')]
```

Here we get the values for Fuel and Dist for each travel (I keep the Id and Express in the grouping clause to have them for the second turn).

```
    ID Express travel V1 V2
1: S36       1      1  2  3
2: S36       0      2  3  3
3: S36       1      3 10  8
4: W09       0      4  5  6
```

And then we sum each category of travel (Express 0 or 1) along with ID:

```
result <- tmp[, list(sum.fuel = sum(V1), sum.dist = sum(V2)), by=c('ID','Express')]
```

Output:

```
    ID Express sum.fuel sum.dist
1: S36       1       12       11
2: S36       0        3        3
3: W09       0        5        6
```

**Drawbacks** I can think of:

- It will behave strangely if the counter loop (99999km loop over to 0 on old trucks for exemple)
- Won't work nicely if the 'travels' are mangled (i.e a local travel for same id start before the express one has ended), I don't know if it could happen in you dataset

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks so much, it looks great!

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table` which is similar to the `dplyr` method in @Frank's post.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[.N] - x[1]) , 
     by =  .(ID, Express, Local, r= rleid(ID, Express, Local)), .SDcols = Fuel:Dist
       ][, lapply(.SD, sum) , by = .(ID, Express, Local), .SDcols = Fuel:Dist]
#    ID Express Local Fuel Dist
#1: S36       1     0   12   11
#2: S36       0     1    3    3
#3: W09       0     1    5    6
```

Comment: Instead of `lapply(.SD, function(x) x[.N] - x[1])` you can do `.SD[.N]-.SD[1L]`, I think.

Comment: @Frank Would that decrease the efficiency?

Comment: I think it would be worse, yeah.